# How do I send an empty JSON dictionary with Guzzle?

Tags: php

I'm trying to post JSON data with PHP using the [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json) library (v7). How do I represent `{}`, the empty dict?

If I do this:

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post('http://localhost:8888', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept'       => 'application/json'
    ],
    'json' => []
]);
```

it sends the JSON "`[]`" as the body. I tried `'json' => array()` but that also sends `[]`.

Comment: `new stdClass()`